# Adding Vlc.DotNet controls to the toolbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, libvlc, toolbox

I am beginning development using the Vlc.DotNet project for my own applications.

I grabbed Vlc.DotNet via the NuGet Package Manager and all 4 of the dlls are successfully listed as references.

I am trying to add the controls to the toolbox.

I have tried going through choose items..., browsing to the packages folder and selecting the dlls for Vlc.DotNet under the newest version of asp.net that is listed.

But I get an error message saying that there are no controls in the dlls to add. I know this is quite incorrect.
So if anyone else has developed with Vlc.DotNet, some help would be very much appreciated. I cannot figure out how to add its controls to the toolbox.
Another article suggests drag and drop with the dlls, this does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I believe all Vlc control operations are now managed through the "VlcControl" control which was located in the Vlc.DotNet.Forms dll

The tutorials in the Vlc.DotNet are outdated, and do not represent this fact.

Comment: I have since dropped VLC.DotNet for axvlc, it is especially helpful that axvlc is already available once vlc is installed on the computer.
Where should i ask if i have a question about _CURRENT_ libvlc functionality? I dont get many responses here

Answer (score 0):

Its been a few years and I see that this question got some views, in the spirit of sharing my subjective knowledge...

even though i eventually figured out VLC's quirks and accounted for them, I found that a better solution was to abandon VLC for a player like MPV player. its been pretty awesome. its well supported, and vlc in any of its forms and forums was consistently rough to decipher and more importantly quirky.

Not to be mean to vlc, but I am now of the opinion that MPV Player is a superior library. I hope that can help some new people to embedded video players have some better luck. I know when I was learning to use these things, nothing ever pointed me towards other video players until i got fed up and went looking

[MPV Main Page](https://mpv.io/)